# Check if two ranges overlap in ruby

Tags: ruby

I know that I can do:

```
(1..30).cover?(2)
=> true
```

But when I try to do the same with another range it always returns false:

```
(1..30).cover?(2..3)
=> false
```

So my question is - is there any elegant way to compare two ranges in ruby? In my case I want to check if two DateTime-ranges overlap. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`Range#overlap?`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Range.html#method-i-overlap-3F) In Ruby 3.3+

It returns `true` if ranges overlap each other, otherwise `false`

It works with different kinds of ranges:

```rb
(5..10).overlap?(10..20)
# => true

('a'..'e').overlap?('b'..'f')
# => true
```

It returns `false` when begin > end:

```rb
(5..1).overlap?(2..3)
# => false
```

It returns `false` when try to check incomparable kinds of ranges:

```rb
(5..10).overlap?('a'..'e') 
# => false
```

It works with exclusive ranges:

```rb
(5..10).overlap?(1...5)
# => false

(1...5).overlap?(5..10)
# => false
```

It works with endless and beginless ranges:

```rb
(1..).overlap?(..1)
# => true

(1..).overlap?(...1)
# => false
```

It raises error when try to pass not range

```rb
(1..5).overlap?(1)
# raise TypeError (expected Range)
```

Answer (score 16):

Two ranges overlap for a given range A when:

1. range B starts within range A,
2. range B ends within range A, or
3. range B starts before range A and ends after range A.

Examples:

```
Range A    |-----|
             |-----|  Case 1
         |-----|      Case 2
             |-|      Case 1 + 2
         |---------|  Case 3
```

Looking closer, the rule is: Two ranges overlap when Range B starts before the range A ends **and** range B ends after the range A starts.

```
def ranges_overlap?(range_a, range_b)
  range_b.begin <= range_a.end && range_a.begin <= range_b.end 
end
```

Or, when you are using the latest version of Ruby, then you can use the [`Range#overlap?`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Range.html#method-i-overlap-3F) method that was introduced in Ruby 3.3, like this:

```
range_a.overlap?(range_b)
```

Comment: The `cover?` method does not check for overlap though, right? `(2..4).cover?(1..3) => false` for example.

Comment: @lsunsi You are right. At the time of writing, I thought that the new `Range#cover?` method would return `true` too when there is only an overlap. But that is not the case. `a.cover?(b)` only returns `true` when `a` complete covers `b`. Partial overlaps will return `false`. I removed the note on `Range#cover?`. It doesn't make sense in the context of the OP's use-case.

Answer (score 8):

```
def overlap?(r1,r2)
  !(r1.first > r2.last || r1.last < r2.first)
end

overlap? 1..5, 4..10 #=> true
overlap? 1..5, 6..10 #=> false
overlap? 1..10, 4..8 #=> true
overlap? 1..4, 4..8  #=> true
```

The operative line is equivalent to:

```
r1.first <= r2.last && r1.last >= r2.first
```

I normally try to avoid negation, but in this case I think it reads better with it.

Another way:

```
def overlap?(r1,r2)
  !(([r1.first, r2.first].min..[r1.last, r2.last].max).size >= r1.size + r2.size)
end

overlap? 1..5, 4..10 #=> true
overlap? 1..5, 6..10 #=> false
overlap? 1..10, 4..8 #=> true
overlap? 1..4, 4..8  #=> true
```

The operative line is equivalent to:

```
([r1.first, r2.first].min..[r1.last, r2.last].max).size < r1.size + r2.size
```

Again, I prefer the one with negation.

Answer (score 5):

In rails You can use `(1..3).overlaps?(2..4) # true`

https://apidock.com/rails/Range/overlaps

Answer (score 5):

If you want the rails implementation you can use

```
class Range
  def overlaps?(other)
    cover?(other.first) || other.cover?(first)
  end
end
```

```
(1..5).overlaps?(4..6) # => true
(1..5).overlaps?(7..9) # => false
```

Comment: This should just go into the ruby stdlib ...

Answer (score 2):

While the conversions may be wasteful, semantically comparing sets seems to make the most sense:

```
Set.new(1..30).superset?(Set.new(2..3))
#=> true
Set.new(1..30).superset?(Set.new(0..3))
#=> false
```

If you don't want to do that, you can do something like this (with `r1` and `r2` being ranges):

```
r1.cover?(r2.min) && r1.cover?(r2.max)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check Overlapping using
`range1.first < range2.last && range2.first < range1.last`
You can add it as an instance method of range or as a helper method somewhere in you data. 
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/4091324

Comment: As `1..3` and `3..5` overlap, you want `<=` rather  than `<`.