# How can I filter by date range and checking overlapping on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, date-range, daterangepicker

I have a Car, Service and Reservation classes. A Car has_many services and reservations. Both services and reservations have "from" and "to" dates, creating a range, which can´t overlap with other reservation's and service's ranges.

I want to filter cars by date ranges. I mean, I want to introduce "from" and "to" dates through date selectors and a submit button in the index, and that the index itself shows me the cars that don´t have any service or reservetion in that period of time.

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39934536/2483313

Comment: Thank you a lot! that was what I have been looking for in hours